# Triangulation of area in boost.Geometry

Tags: c++, boost, triangulation, boost-geometry

I use boost.Geometry to do some calculation resulting in an `boost::geometry::model::multipolygon`. I calculate it's area using `boost::geometry::area`. Besides using the numeric value I'd like to display the area for debugging/development purposes. I have a library to create and display meshes.

I understand that `boost::geometry::area` internally performs a triangulation of the `multi_polygon` for calculation of the area. Is there a way to access the calculated triangles for creating meshes? The default strategy (`boost::geometry::strategy::area::surveyor`) is used, but I can't find the place in the implementation where the triangulation is done.

Comment: Dunno about `boost::geometry`, but you don't need to triangulate a polygon in order to compute its area.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. In Boost.Geometry any triangulation isn't performed to calculate the area of a Polygon. E.g. in cartesian coordinate system the [Surveyor's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) is used by default.